# Understanding of a proposition about linearly independet and span

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$ and let $A\subseteq V$. Then $A$ is linearly independet if and only if for any $v\in A$, $v\not\in$ Span$(A\backslash \left\{ v\right\})$.

I couldn'u understand this proposition, why for any $v\in A$, $v\not\in$ Span$(A\backslash \left\{ v\right\})$? Can you explain? And so, is it important the proposition,if yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some $v\in A$.  What would it mean if $v\in\text{Span}(A\setminus\{v\})$?  It would mean that we could write 
$$
v=\alpha_1w_1+\cdots+\alpha_nw_n,
$$
for some $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in K$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_n\in A$, $v\neq w_i$ for any $i$.  But then this means in turn that $A$ contains both $w_1,\ldots,w_n$, AND a linear combination of these vectors... meaning that $A$ is not a linearly independent set of vectors.  This proves that if $A$ is a linearly independent set, then for all $v\in A$ we have $v\notin\text{Span}(A\setminus\{v\})$.

What about the other direction? See if you can prove this.  There are perfectly good ways to prove it either directly or by contradiction.

Comment: If $v\in Span(A \backslash \{v\})$ this would imply that $v=\alpha_{1}w_{1},...,\alpha_{i}w_{i}$ and $v\neq w_{i}$. This implies $v-\alpha_{1}w_{1},...,\alpha_{i}w_{i}=0$. You can look at the definition of linear independence and see how this gives us a contradiction. New to linear algebra here and was trying to understand this answer and I felt like putting this explicitly might help. Hope my comments are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the statement say that any vector of $A$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of the other vectors.